# Access 2010 VBA to put one field from a query in a variable

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

In Access 2010 I need to be able to click a command button that will run a query that returns a small two field recordset.  Then put the second field in that recordset into a string variable.

This string variable is a link to a word document on the network.  the second part of the code will then open the word document.
Any help is GREATLY appreciated.

I am getting the Error: "Object variable or With block variable not set"

My Code looks like this:

```
    `Option Compare Database

Private Sub cmdCESpec_Click()

On Error GoTo Err_cmdCESpec_Click
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim s As String
Dim specSheet As String

s = "SELECT p.PartNum, p.CE_SpecSheet FROM tblParts p WHERE p.PartNum = '" & [Forms]![frmSpecSheet]![cboPartNum] & "'" 'Chooses the correct Spec Sheet.
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(s)

specSheet = rs.Fields("CE_SpecSheet")  'Chooses the Spec Sheet Field


rs.Close

    Dim oApp As Object

    Set oApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    oApp.Visible = True

    With oApp
        .Documents.Open (specSheet)
    End With

Exit_cmdCESpec_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_cmdCESpec_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_cmdCESpec_Click

End Sub
```

Comment: You should include things you have already tried and code that you have written to attempt this functionality (don't include your document opening code unless it is relevant). This will increase the likeliness that someone will help! Thanks.

Comment: I've tried posting a general sort of answer but Michal is correct, the better you frame your question, the better the answer you tend to receive as a result.

Comment: Open your VBA in the editor and right click in the left margin next to the line "On Error GoTo Err_cmdCESpec_Click".  This will put a red dot in the column, which is a BREAK POINT.  Run the code.  It will stop at that line and highlight it in yellow.  Press the F8 key.  It will move to the next line.  Do this, line by line, until you get that error message.  Take note of the line it happened on, and edit your question to include this information.  It will make debugging the issue a LOT easier for us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After dissecting your code.. this:

```
"..WHERE (((tblParts.PartNum)=[Forms]![frmSpecSheet]![cboPartNum]));"
```

embeds the *words* Forms!etc into your sql-statement, it doesn't insert the combo-box value into the statement.

You need to take the form reference out of the string:

```
    Dim db As Database
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Dim s As String
    Dim specSheet As String
    s = "SELECT tblParts.PartNum, tblParts.CE_SpecSheet FROM tblParts WHERE " _
        & "tblParts.PartNum=" & [Forms]![frmSpecSheet]![cboPartNum]
    'Chooses the Correct Spec Sheet
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(s)
    specSheet = rs.Fields("CE_SpecSheet")
    'Chooses the Spec Sheet Field
    rs.Close
    Dim oApp As Object
    Set oApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    oApp.Visible = True
    With oApp
        .Documents.Open ("specSheet")
    End With
```

If the combobox's value is text then you'll need to also surround this with apostrophes.

You also don't need to SELECT the field `tblParts.PartNum`, you can just refer to it in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted much information but what I gather you're looking for is `Recordset`

```
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim s As String
Dim myString As String

s = "SELECT * FROM myTable1;" 'Replace with the SQL you need
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(s)

myString = rs.Fields("myFieldName1")  'Replace myFieldName with the appropriate field name

rs.Close
```

Comment: @ a shareef This is VERY Close to what I am trying to do. I have this as my code:
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim s As String
Dim specSheet As String
s = "SELECT tblParts.PartNum, tblParts.CE_SpecSheet FROM tblParts WHERE (((tblParts.PartNum)=[Forms]![frmSpecSheet]![cboPartNum]));" 'Chooses the Correct Spec Sheet
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(s)
specSheet = rs.Fields("CE_SpecSheet")  'Chooses the Spec Sheet Field
rs.Close
Dim oApp As Object
Set oApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
oApp.Visible = True
With oApp
     .Documents.Open ("specSheet")
    End With

Comment: In the future please edit these kind of information into your original question.  And even though you have posted your code now you haven't explained what you're still having trouble with this answer.  Please clarify.